# Can i write col-xs-12 for all viewport..?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a doubt. If I want same col size like `col-*-12` for all view port, shall I write simply `col-xs-12` (or) `col-xs-12` and `col-sm-12` (or) separate `col-*-12` classes for all view ports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want col size **col-12** you dont need to write it al all...

Comment: definately, if you are using same for all viewport you can simply write col-md-12 for all

Comment: Let suppose i want to write col-xs-12 and col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8, should i write all the classes as i show you..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column classes in Bootstrap apply to viewports greater than or equal to the minimum size for the class.

For example, the `sm` classes apply to viewports **>= 768px**, while `lg` applies to viewports **>= 1200px**. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

This means you only need to add the class for the minimum viewport size you want.

If you end up with: `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6`, you can minimise it down to: `col-xs-12 col-sm-6` and all viewports over 768px wide will have the `col-sm-6` style applied.